# Unit Testing : cellForItem(at: IndexPath.init(item: 0, section: 0)) returns nil for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, xctestcase

I am running into a very weird problem where my code for unit testing a UiCollectionViewCell returns nil.

```
var indexPath = IndexPath.init(item: 0, section: 0)

let cell = libraryGridViewController?.libraryCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
```

This collection view is attached to the datasource by RxSwift binding.

Though while debugging I observed that numberOfItems(inSection: 0) returns the desired number of items in data-array.

```
(lldb) po libraryGridViewController!.libraryCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
```

4

Please let me know what could have possibly gone wrong here. I just want a valid cell to be returned from the method - cellForItem.  Thanks!

Comment: Nil is a valid return value if the cell at the requested index path isn't on screen. Has the cell been shown?

Comment: @Paulw11 The cell is not shown in the screen. This code is for unit testing the datasource call to load a dequeued cell. I have a similar code for a UITableView which works fine for the method - cellForRow.

Comment: Update: I could access / get the UICollectionViewCell object by making a call to datasource method as follows.. this code has an affirmative assertion result -'XCTAssertNotNil(libraryGridViewController?.libraryCollectionView.dataSource?.collectionView((libraryGridViewController?.libraryCollectionView)!, cellForItemAt: indexPath))'

Comment: @SwarupPattnaik this comment just saved me after several hours of scratching my head.  My UITableView, tested in the same way, was working just fine - what's the difference in two data structures that would cause this failure?

Comment: @SwarupPattnaik Add you comment as answer. It works and should be accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: I did this collection view.datasource.collectionview(...)... thing and it works. Thanks @SwarupPattnaik